# Как регирует сервер, на большое количество подключений?

Tags: include, сервер, php

Всем привет, проблема такая, в php новичок. Не знаю, как лучше подключать множество файлов **include** или запихать все функции в один файл. Как реагирует сервер?

```
include ('./system/config.php');
include ('./system/pattern.php');
include ('./pattern/index.php');
```

Так получается около 6 подключений.

Comment: Если разницы и есть, то это экономия на спичках, **делайте так, как вам удобнее**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Серверу практически все равно, сколько вы подключаете файлов к той или иной PHP-странице. Это никак не влияет на скорость обработки сервером поступающих от пользователей всякого рода запросов. Ведь, как вам, надеюсь, известно, что на место include тупо подставляется PHP код, содержащийся в подключаемом файле. require и *_once аналоги действуют очень похоже, но там идет ряд определенных проверок, например, на то, был ли файл уже подключен ранее. Я же вам хотел бы сказать насчет многократных вызовов инклуда, что этого можно избежать, ведь много инклудов запутывают. Избежать можно, например, объединяя весь код со сходным функционалом в один файл. Все классы, например, засунуть можно в один файл, все писанные вами функции для работы со строками - в другой и т.д. Но бывают и исключения, где вы должны будете уже сообразить сами.

---

А вообще, если вы делаете акцент на производительность, то скажу прямо - не там ищете! Подключение-не подключение доп.файлов - это, как уже неоднократно говорилось другими участниками - "экономия на спичках". В таком случае вам лучше почитать о архитектуре высокопроизводительных систем, memcached и т.д...

Comment: спасибо, буду изучать :)

Answer (score 1):

Топик стартер страдает преждевременной оптимизацией. Проводились ли замеры? с большой вероятностью - нет.

Открытие файла - это конечно нагрузка, но если к какому то файлу часто обращаются, то он оказывается в кеше и доступ к нему будет очень быстрым.

Если в какой то момент не будет хватать скорости, то следует применять более кардинальные методы. Например [HipHop](http://habrahabr.ru/post/85092/) от Facebook.

Если скорости ещё не будет хватать, то нужно оптимизировать алгоритмы.

Comment: HipHop от Facebook хоть и очень полезная штуковина, но она еще не так популяризирована.

Answer (score 0):

*Чисто теоретически, выгоднее будет запихать в один файл, а **на практике, нагрузка сервера тем что он откроет плюс ещё один файл будет крайне мала.***

---

### Поместить код в другой файл.

- Код будет удобнее читаться
- Легче искать ошибки

### Поместить код в один файл.

- Сложнее его потом изменять
- Можно запутаться
- Сложнее найти ошибку

Comment: т.е. лучше запихать все в один файл?
Мне кажется, что культурнее будет если каждый кусок кода в своем файле, в своей папке. Но главное, что меня волнует, это поведение сервера. Я понимаю, что 1,2 подключенных файла это нормально, но когда их около 6 это пугает.

Comment: @niki-timofe

       Чисто теоретически выгоднее

категорически не согласен!

Comment: @Asen, @knyazsergei, я за то что бы раскидать по инклюдам, поэтому и выделил вторую часть...

> Чисто теоретически выгоднее будет запихать в один файл

 1. Это только на первый взгляд.
 2. Все аргументы, которые я привёл после пунктирной линии против того чтобы поместить код в один файл.

Comment: @niki-timofe, "чисто теоритически" у бабушки яй*и не вырастут =)

Comment: @Asen, а так предложение *кривое* получается.